# How do I enable supplied backend authentication in the Airflow 2.1.0 version?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have installed Airflow 2.1.0 version recently. But unable to find an option to enable airflow login authentication with supplied backend like in older versions. Can you anyone help me in providing steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Airflow 2.0, Airflow's basic auth for the UI is the default behavior. You can consult the following documentation to read that:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/webserver.html

If you want to use different security backends, you will need to provide an additional configuration file at your `$AIRFLOW_HOME` dir, the `webserver_config.py`. It will load its configuration to Flask-AppBuilder, and have the ability to define various security backends.

Some links:

1. [Airflow documentation on Other Security Methods](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/webserver.html#other-methods)
2. [Flask-AppBuilder documentation](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html)
3. [example webserver_config.py file from Airflow's repository](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/config_templates/default_webserver_config.py)